# The use of the word "along"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Say I want someone to fold a rectangular sheet of paper so that I get a cylinder with the longer side as its height.

> Roll the sheet of paper along its shorter side.

Is this correct? Or should it be along the longer side?

Comment: I think you'd say "roll the sheet of paper [lengthways](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lengthways)" or "lengthwise", or maybe "parallel to the longest side". "Along" here seems ambiguous.

Comment: Agreed about the ambiguity, and not using "along". It reads to me that you are actually wanting to roll up the short side; the long side remains straight. Perhaps something like "Lay the paper with one of the long sides closest to you, then roll it up away from yourself", or "place a pencil along one of the long sides, then roll it up around the pencil". Otherwise your original description is clear, though you haven't specified how *tightly* to roll up the paper.

Comment: Referring to the untouched short side is a mistake. *Starting at one of the long edges, roll the paper ...*